# How can I get a stable Photoshop running on Linux?

Tags: linux, adobe-photoshop, wine

My OS is Debian - I've heard of Wine and virtualization software such as Virtualbox.. I'm wondering what to go with for stability as Wine was kinda bug prone when I last tried it for some other Windows software.

Comment: updated question.

Comment: I wonder what the performance will be if you virtualize it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I went ahead and installed VirtualBox 3, gave it around 500 MB of virtual memory and it seems very very stable.

Photoshop CS4 runs fine inside XP, now if I could only mount my main local filesystem inside of XP without resorting to one shared directory that'd be nice :)

Answer (score 4):

[Crossover](http://codeweavers.com) officially supports Photoshop as "silver".  This means that there are some bugs, but they're working on improving support.  They also have an extensive [tips section](http://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/browse/name/?app_id=8;tips=1).

(Crossover is a commercial version of Wine)

Answer (score 3):

Use [VMWare Workstation](http://www.vmware.com/download/ws/) with a Windows XP or Windows Vista Installation. The latest version provides you functionality to access the application integrated to the Desktop Environment. , That is, you can run a Windows application in a window on your Linux Desktop.

Photoshop will work like a native Linux application, while the process runs under the virtual machine.

Answer (score 2):

- There are notes at [**Running Adobe Photoshop on Wine**](http://wiki.winehq.org/AdobePhotoshop) Wiki
  (check if you have all that covered already).
- There are [Adobe Photoshop **Alternatives For Linux Desktop**](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/adobe-photoshop-alternatives-for-linux-desktop/),

  - and, some more for Linux also at [31 Free & Powerful **Photoshop Alternatives**](http://techflaps.com/2009/08/31-free-powerful-photoshop-alternatives/).
- There is also a Stackoverflow question: [Best way to use **Photoshop CS3 in Linux**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282782/best-way-to-use-photoshop-cs3-in-linux).
- Then, you can vote @PollDaddy: [**Would you buy Adobe software if it were available on Linux**](http://answers.polldaddy.com/poll/1385972/)